# Dapper multiple insert records and return identity

Tags: dapper

I've been evaluating Dapper to replace EF6 that we have been using.

One of the use cases involves inserting multiple records in a table where we need to return the identity column and another DB set datetime column.

To illustrate - consider table

```
Create Table Demo
(
   Id int indentity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(10),
   WhenCreated DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

I know I can insert multiple records using  Connection.Execute  -- 
But this does not return me Id, Whencreated columns.

```
var connection = new SqlConnection();
var names = new []{ {Name = "Name1"}, {Name = "Name2"}};
connection.Execute("Insert into Demo(Name) values(@Name)", names );
```

To return identity data I could use Connection.Query

```
var connection = new SqlConnection();
var demo = connection.Query<Demo>(
     @"Insert into Demo(Name) values(@Name); 
       Select * from Demo Where Id = Scope_IDENTITY();", 
     new {Name = "Name1"} );
```

But this can only be done for one record at a time - i.e. each record is one round trip to the server which is not feasible.

---

**Essentially I'm looking for way to this (this does not work - since Query does not take / map a collection) - i.e. insert multiple records in one server trip and return identities (or indeed any other columns) for all the inserted rows**

```
var connection = new SqlConnection();
var names = new []{ {Name = "Name1"}, {Name = "Name2"}};
var demo = connection.Query<Demo>(
     @"Declare @Inserted Table (Id int);
       Insert into Demo(Name) OUTPUT Inserted.Id into @Inserted
                values(@Name); 
       Select * from @Inserted",
     names );
```

Comment: The last part should work, just change OUTPUT to "OUTPUT Inserted.Id, Inserted.Name, Insert.WhenCreated into @Inserted" + Change the declaring table to be with all columns